# Ways to use PHP 5 and 7 parallel on same LAMP Installation

Tags: apache-2.4, php5, lamp, php7

Dear all I am currently having a **LAMP** installation with PHP v5 on an Ubuntu 16.x machine. I like now to update it with PHP v7 but I like to have both configurations available so I can easily migrate my websites to new PHP v7.

The problem of LAMPP itself is you can not have multiple LAMPP versions installed in parallel because the LAMPP installation paths are "hardcoded" and can not be changed during installation. LAMPP itself supports also not FastCGI / PHP-FPM out of the box.

It gets quite hard on an Ubuntu system to install php-fpm stuff with the standard packages because they are managed and installed outside of LAMPP and are pre-pared for the official apache installation on ubuntu (pre-defined paths etc.)

Does anyone have experience and like to share as a step to step guideline here how to install PHP-FPM without the pre-defined packag installer (apt-get) so it can be integrated into LAMPP installation?

Comment: This ends up being the same question that was answered here: "http://serverfault.com/questions/833380/how-to-allow-to-change-php-version-via-htaccess-in-apache/833418". Basically you can't if you use mod_php, but you can if you use reverse proxy modules to php-fpm.

Comment: Update I don't agree that this question  is the same as a simple apache installation. LAMPP itself is a whole package and does not support out of the box mutliple PHP version nor does it support  out of the box php - fpm. So you need quite some tweaks to get it running with multiple PHP instalaltions on an ubuntu system where its standard installation packages are managed (different installation paths as LAMPP). You also can only have one LAMPP installation because installation path is hard coded by its provider